# Removing the eventual trailing '\n' in a string in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I need to create a function that receives a string and checks if the last char is a "\n" or not. If so, returns the same string without it's last char.
The ways I can think of doing this are not the slightest efficient. I need it to be efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to give a precise answer to your question as you do not give any context.

The simplest solution I can think of is:

```
let check s =
  let n = String.length s in
  if n > 0 && s.[n-1] = '\n' then
    String.sub s 0 (n-1)
  else
    s
```

Comment: You mean: if n > 0 && s.[n-1] = '\n' then

Comment: I created a method that produced a very long string and I in some cases produced a "\n" in the end that I didn't want. Since I was near over schedule, I didn't have time to re-think it, so a fix like this seemed the solution xD. Thanks, you saved my project!

Comment: @MartinJambon is right, I forgot to handle the case where the size of n is 0. I've edited my answer accordingly.